# Could not find method lombok() for arguments

Tags: java, gradle, plugins, build, lombok

Just wanted to include the lombok plugin with my gradle build but get the error message from the title. My build.gradle looks like this:

```
...
plugins {
    id 'net.ltgt.apt' version '0.10'
}
ext {
    lombok_version="1.16.18"
}
lombok {
    version = ${lombok_version}
    sha256 = ""
}
...
dependencies {
    ...    
    compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombok_version}"
    apt "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombok_version}"
    ...
}
```

Source: https://projectlombok.org/setup/gradle

Any ideas what's wrong here? If I remove the lombok {...} part everything works fine.

Comment: Note, to tell the gradle-lombok plugin to use the latest version of lombok, you need to explicitly tell it about the latest version number and the SHA-256 <- did you read the setup guide

Comment: well the version number is there. regarding SHA256 i copied the code from the link shared above. however if I go to the "about guide" (https://github.com/franzbecker/gradle-lombok) it says that the sha256 parameter can be set to null or empty to skip verification. btw. just added the hash value, error remains

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://projectlombok.org/setup/gradle) you should use either

```
lombok {
    version = "1.16.18"
    sha256 = ""
}
```

or

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.18'
    apt "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.18"
}
```

Disclosure: I am a lombok developer.

Comment: It took me a while to find out that I need `testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.18'`, too. Could you add it to the doc?

Comment: Why can't se use **annotationProcessor**?

Comment: @Roel I tested this on a multi module project, I've added what you stated above and it's still not working. Any idea? I've an old project using gradle wrapper 2.12

Comment: I'm not a gradle specialist, but I've read from other sources that updating the wrapper solved their problem. Also, you need to add the lombok configuration to all modules. Hope that helps.

Comment: Oh, and possibly `apt` needs to be replaced by `annotationProcessor`